# Change virtualenv colours in bash (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv, bash

I tried to find a solution for this for a few days but couldn't. Already checked .bashrc and tried to find a config file of virtualenv to see where the "(twitchoverlay)" part of the image is located.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyct6.png

Any help of tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 5 more minutes of reseach did the trick. I just had to:

- go to my $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR
- cd my twitchovelay env
- nano the activate file
- locate the line where the export to PS1 is located and add the colours